# Cannot use tailwind classes

Tags: html, web, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

Im new to nodejs and tailwindcss, i followed installation tutorial from the official installation documentation from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation. But after doing all the steps, somehow i still cannot use the tailwind classes. Is there any extra steps that i need to follow or is there something wrong somewhere?

I already tried reinstalling tailwindcss and even node but the problem still there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the `tailwindcss` package, switch to the directory where you will use tailwind from the command line. Then run the following command:

```sh
mkdir project_directory
cd project_directory
npx tailwindcss init
```

Update the automatically generated `tailwind.config.js` file in the `project_directory/` directory

```js
module.exports = {
   content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
   theme: {
     extend: {},
   },
   plugins: [],
}
```

Create `input.css file` in `/project_directory/src/` directory and add component declarations:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

When you use the following command, `/project_directory/dist/output.css` file will be created in `/dist/` directory:

```sh
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Add this file as a reference in the `index.html` file:

```html
<link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The project directory structure is as follows:

```
project_directory/
   |
   |--- tailwind.config.js
   |
   |--- dist/
   |       | 
   |       |--- output.css 
   |
   |--- src/ 
           |
           |--- input.css
           |
           |--- index.html
           |
           |--- main.js
```

The `tailwindcss` command instantly monitors the changes in the `/src/input.css` file at runtime and automatically updates the `/dist/output.css` file.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem by following the steps I mentioned? If you can't figure it out, refer to the [CDN method](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn) to use tailwindcss.