# Why does my tailwind output file not include the utilities and components

Tags: tailwind-css

I've installed tailwind using `npm install tailwindcss`
I then create my src/style.css file and include

```
    `@tailwind base;`
    `@tailwind components;`
    `@tailwind utilities;`
```

When I run my build-css command I get a generated output.css file, but the file is only 425 lines long. It looks likes it's missing the components and the utilities. When I link my HTML to the output.css I get the base tailwind css styles applied, but utilities have absolutely no effect. I have followed the docs to the best of my ability as well as several tutorials with the same result every time. No clue what I am I doing wrong, the tuts I have watched show this file to be thousands of lines of code while mine is always 425.

Comment: Which version of Tailwind CSS are you using? Is it v2.x or v3?

Comment: I'm using tailwindcss v3

Comment: can you share with us your taiwind.config file?

Comment: It only include classes you actually used in your html / css / ..

Comment: On step 6 of the tutorial I am following on the tailwind website here: `https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss`, it adds a link element to the index.html to reference the generated main.css file. However the URL for the link reference is "/dist/main.css". When I reference "/dist/main.css" in my project, it doesn't work. When I manually go to "/dist/main.css" from the Chrome browser, I see the html for index.html

Comment: You may be following version 1 instructions, but running a newer version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a config js file for the tailwind engine, inside the config file use `content` attribute to define where is your HTML or JS files, the new engine automatically looks inside these files and compiles only the classes that you used.

Check this video for more information:https://youtu.be/mSC6GwizOag?t=22

Comment: I don't want to learn how to configure anything, I just want to do it manually for now. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

If you believe you have set everything up properly, check that the structure of the project directory is correct:

```
project_directory/
   |
   |--- tailwind.config.js
   |
   |--- dist/
   |       | 
   |       |--- output.css 
   |
   |--- src/ 
           |
           |--- input.css
           |
           |--- index.html
           |
           |--- main.js
```

---

###### References

- [Cannot use tailwind classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452240/15032688)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build ./src/styles.css -o ./public/styles.css

ps: the styles.css in the public folder is the output.css

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It was my config file, I wasn't point to my source file correctly. Fixed this by coping the documentation's example and file structure. `content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],` was what I needed to add to the tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had spaces in the file extensions that cause my problem

```
   module.exports = {
     content: ['./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
     //wrong content: ['./app/**/*.{js, ts, jsx, tsx}'],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    };
```